# query google groups api from gcp instance/function python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, service-accounts

I'm trying to create a script to query google groups API from GCP instance. The instance has SA attached to it, this SA has SCOPE - 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly' allowed in GSuite, and the user is also setup in GSuite with a custom role attached to it(list groups).

For the SA I created a key file in GCP console. Then I get the credentials as documentation says:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
```

then add the user - to act as.

```
creds = creds.with_subject('user@domain.com')

service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)

results = service.groups().list(domain=tenant, maxResults=10,
                    orderBy='email',
                    query='email:{}*'.format(group_name)).execute()
```

Then I query API, everything works perfect and I get the groups.

So my question is:
Is there a way to use the SA attached to the instance without generating the json key file. Like get compute_instance / default credentials / from instance metadata and then somehow authenticate them to the GSuite API?

Or is there a way to query groups without hitting Gsuite API, just call some from within GCP?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [next](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances) article on the official GCP Documentation page

Here is an example of how to bind service account to VM

```
gcloud compute instances create example-vm \
--service-account my-sa@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers I got from google:

1. No, it's not possible without generating a private key for SA for impersonation.
2. No, the right way of getting the groups is to query Gsuite's APIs.